# Giving spaces between rows in a (multicolumn) table

Tags: tables, multirow

I managed to make a multicolumn table, but it looks ugly and need some fix.

1. How to move the label "Min width" in the center?
2. How to give more  space between the first and second row?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{String}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{c | cc | cc }
\toprule
Min width  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$fp_{c}$} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{$fp_{bf}$} \\ \cline{2-5}
 & theory & exp & theory & exp  \\
\midrule
1 & 0.23\% & 0.21\% & 0.04\% & 0.065\% \\
2 & 0.085\% & 0.087\% & 0.0015\% & 0.0020\% \\
3 & 0.032\% & 0.026\% & $5.5\times 10^{-4}$\% & 0\% \\
4 & 0.012\% & 0.011\% & $2.1\times 10^{-4}$\% & 0\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:fp_probabilities}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [tag:multicol] tag is wrong here, since it is connected to another concept. You need the `\multirows` command from `multirow` package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You must have editing rights by now on this site -- just go ahead and correct the tags as you see fit.

Comment: @Mico: Of course I could have edited it myself, but I wanted to leave it to the OP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, remove vertical lines. For spacing properly the headers, as others stated, use `booktabs`, no doubt. For the multirow cell "Min width" is better use a `\parbox` or a `minipage` sice there are only a column of single digits.  Also it is better add some space to the caption, that without additional packages can be done tuning  `\belowcaptionskip.`

On the other hand, make the table simple as possible. If all your data are percentages, you can show information in the headers of each column, but it is better if you simply use the caption for that.

With respect to the columns, may be is better add some spacing between columns 3 and 4 to distinguish the two groups of data. A simple way is add an empty column or play with the column separators (`@{}`).

Finally, in  *this* example I prefer do not follow decimal alignment because the uneven decimal columns in *this* case do not help too munch to distinguish numbers above or below 1 (waiting opposing views in 3, 2 ...) `:)`

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{5pt} 

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{String (\%)} 
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{cccccc} %  
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{
\parbox[c]{.2\linewidth}{\centering Min width}}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$fp_{c}$} &&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$fp_{bf}$} \\ 
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{5-6}

 & {\centering theory} & {exp.} && {theory} & {exp.}  \\
\midrule
1 & 0.23  & 0.21  && 0.04               & 0.065 \\
2 & 0.085 & 0.087 && 0.0015             & 0.0020 \\
3 & 0.032 & 0.026 && $5.5\times10^{-4}$ & 0 \\
4 & 0.012 & 0.011 && $5.5\times10^{-4}$ & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution. I used `siunitx` to have a vertical alignment of numbers in columns and a simplified typing of scientific notation, `makecell` to have multirow cells that allow for line breaking and to have less tight rows, `caption` for a correct vertical spacing betwen caption and table. Also I added some color, and deleted vertical rules: this is bad typographical practice.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc}
\setlength\cmidrulewidth{1.2\lightrulewidth}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-figures-exponent=1, table-sign-exponent=true}
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{String}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c*{2}{S[table-format=1.3]}@{\qquad}*{2}{S[table-format=1.4]}}
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$fp_{c}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$fp_{bf}$} \\
\arrayrulecolor{LightSteelBlue3}
\cmidrule(lr{2em}){2-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}
\multirowcell{-3}{Min\\ width} & {theory (\%)} & {exp(\%)} & {theory(\%)} & {exp(\%)} \\
\cmidrule(lr{2em}){2-3}\cmidrule(r){4-5}
1 & 0.23 & 0.21 & 0.04 & 0.065 \\
2 & 0.085 & 0.087 & 0.0015 & 0.0020 \\
3 & 0.032 & 0.026 & \num{5.5 e-4} & 0 \\
4 & 0.012 & 0.011 & \num{2.1 e-4} & 0 \\
\arrayrulecolor{Tomato3}\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:fp_probabilities}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Always avoid vertical lines in `booktabs` since the commands provided by `booktabs` work correctly only in absence of vertical rules. Also you need `multirow` package and you can improve the table by inserting the `%` sign in headings and align numbers at the `.` floating point. With these in mind, you can get this table:

[image]

The modified code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{String}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c*{2}{r@{.}l}{c}*{2}{r@{.}l}@{}}
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Min width} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$fp_{c}$} && \multicolumn{4}{c}{$fp_{bf}$}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule{2-5} \cmidrule{7-10}
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{theory \%} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{exp \%} && \multicolumn{2}{l}{theory \%} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{exp \%}\tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 0&23  & 0&21  &&  0&04                & 0&065  \tabularnewline
2 & 0&085 & 0&087 &&  0&0015              & 0&0020 \tabularnewline
3 & 0&032 & 0&026 &&  5&$5\times 10^{-4}$ & 0&0    \tabularnewline
4 & 0&012 & 0&011 &&  2&$1\times 10^{-4}$ & 0&0    \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:fp_probabilities}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note: Pay attention to the table width as you are using `twocolumn`. Otherwise use either `sidewaystable` or make the table occupy both columns

Comment: What does your column setup code do that couldn't be achieved more easily as `*{4}{l}`?

Comment: We don't have any 4 consecutive left aligned columns. The only repetitive form is `r@{.}l` isn't it?

Comment: The screenshot makes it look like there are four data columns whose contents are left-aligned, doesn't it?

Comment: We have `@{.}` separating two columns, so we can't combine them in single alignment. Besides, if we use `l@{.}l` and it happens that one of the numbers has 2 digits to the left of the `.`, we get wrong alignment

Comment: I guess my point is that instead of creating 8 columns (with pairs of columns joined by the decimal marker) and splitting the numbers in the table into integer and decimal components, wouldn't it be easier to leave the numbers alone and employ either the `dcolumn` package or the `siunitx` package to provide a column type that performs alignment on the decimal marker?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proposed solution which (a) makes more consistent use of the macros of the `booktabs` package (no `\cline`, but a couple of `\cmidrule`s), (b) uses the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package to align the numbers on the decimal markers, (c) simplifies the content of the table by moving the common unit information (`(%)`) into a separate header row, and (d) deliberately *does not* break the string "min width" across two rows, in order to preserve a visual balance between the first column that contains the labels and the remaining columns that contain the data.

Separately, loading the `caption` package automatically inserts a bit of vertical whitespace between the caption and the tabular. Finally, as others have already remarked, simply don't use vertical lines in a table, regardless of whether you use the `booktabs` package or not: A well-designed table should be able to make do without the vertical bars and will, almost certainly, look a whole lot better than one with vertical bars.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4,tight-spacing=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{String} \label{tbl:fp_probabilities}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{@{} c *{4}{S} @{}}  % 1 'c' column, 4 'S' columns
\toprule
Min width  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$fp_{c}$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$fp_{bf}$} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
 & {theory} & {exp} & {theory} & {exp}  \\
 & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} & {(\%)} \\
\midrule
1 & 0.23 & 0.21 & 0.04 & 0.065 \\
2 & 0.085 & 0.087 & 0.0015 & 0.0020 \\
3 & 0.032 & 0.026 & \num{5.5e-4} & 0 \\
4 & 0.012 & 0.011 & \num{2.1e-4} & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

the same thing. however, \multirows command and package multirow is to be used as suggested by Christian Hupfer
Code

```
\documentclass[11pt, twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{String}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{c | cc | cc }
\toprule
\multirow{5}{*}{Min width} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$fp_{c}$} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c}{$fp_{bf}$} \\ 
& & \\ \cline{2-5}
& & &\\
&theory & exp& theory & exp  \\ 
& & &\\
\midrule
1 & 0.23\% & 0.21\% & 0.04\% & 0.065\% \\
2 & 0.085\% & 0.087\% & 0.0015\% & 0.0020\% \\
3 & 0.032\% & 0.026\% & $5.5\times 10^{-4}$\% & 0\% \\
4 & 0.012\% & 0.011\% & $2.1\times 10^{-4}$\% & 0\% \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tbl:fp_probabilities}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: space]

Comment: Please remember to indent lines of LaTeX code by four spaces so that they can get pretty-printed by the site's software. Indenting the lines in this manner is achieved easily by simply highlighting them and clicking on the `{}` button in the ribbon above the editing window.

Comment: You should always avoid vertical rules in `booktabs` to have it working correctly.